# How i can retrieve element by _id using Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to get element by _id (mongodb id) but I get empty results:

```
puts (MyModel.where(image: '11201529185526851unnamed-(1).jpg')).first._id
# => '565b58e0cdb451125e00001d'
```

and when I try to get data with this _id:

```
puts (MyModel.where(__id: '565b58e0cdb451125e00001d')).first.inspect
# => nil
```

I didn't extend ActiveRecord.

Comment: Why do you need to again pass an id to get a record if you've already got one ?

Comment: store the result fo this `MyModel.where(image: '11201529185526851unnamed-(1).jpg')).first` in some var and use it

Comment: i need to find element by __id not image 
 i use image field  to Make sure it return true _id 
and i need to find by _id
 for interaction between my web service and mobile Application
and    _id is unique identity